# Column Header is in all caps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have an activeadmin app that has a colum label in all caps and can't seem to get rid of it. `column("Status", :order_status, :sortable => :order_status_id)`

[image: The status column stays in all caps, no matter what I do]

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess... may be you have a `text-transform: uppercase;` CSS rule somewhere in your stylesheets?

Comment: I appreciate the guess, but i searched my entire app but nothing like that code appeared. I find it funny that just the word status is in all caps and not any of the other headers are in caps. I have the same code for all of those columns as well.

Comment: Did you use the DOM inspector to check the computed style? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles. Other alternative is to browse the source code of active admin and track the line which prints the column label.